# Maven compile huge Java file

Tags: maven, compiler-construction

I have a Java-File which holds WSDL-Strings for testing purposes.
The file has 469kb Eclipse compiles the Project without problems.
But when i try "mvn clean compile" i get an error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:2062)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:2062)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:2062)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:2062)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)

...

        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.265s
```

my compiler plugin is configured like that

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

i already tried to set

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

in my windows7

why can eclipse compile this file but maven not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not Maven but the Java compiler itself. But even if the compiler would not crash you will quite likly exeed the class file's `code_length` of [64 KiB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#9279).

I suggest splitting the Java source into multiple source files.

Comment: which compiler does eclipse use? can't i use it with maven?

Comment: or can you suggest me a good possibility how to store multi-line resource-strings in java?

Comment: If you just need strings, why not use resource files? You can load a resource with [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: you mean one file per string?

Comment: If you use a [properties file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) you can put all your strings into one file and access them by name (as you would with using variable names inside a Java source)

Comment: but multiline support is verry ugly... is there a better solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [XML representation](http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd) of Java properties where multiline is supported without special annotations with [Properties.loadFromXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: ok xml is not good for me, because my strings contain XML... but i now use the multiPorperties-Editor for eclipse which supports multiline in it's latest version and creates the properties files for me

Comment: As last suggestion: you can use [<![CDATA[](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) to escape XML inside XML without much trouble :)